# Keeping DB connection alive during distributed transaction

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, transactions, xa

I have a long running distributed transaction in Java using EJBs on JBoss EAP 6.2. The thing is that at first I have to modify data in one database and then call some web services multiple times and depending on the results I get from these web services I have to modify data in the same database as well.

These web services are kind of slow and a stateful firewall I have between application server and the database server kills a connection to database before transaction ends because it's inactive for some time. I cannot reconfigure said firewall.

My question is: what would be the best way to keep a database connection alive throughout a whole transaction?

Answer (score 0):

To recapitulate your requirements. You need to:

1. Perform update operations on DB1.
2. Perform various WS operations.
3. Depending on outcome of step 2, update DB2.

Then you say that your problem is to keep alive your database connection. You don't mention which, but I guess that must be for DB2. You're also talking about transactions so I guess that you must use a Session Bean with CMT or BMT.

What I think is that you experiencing a transaction timeout rather that db connection timeout.
I don't work with EAP but from my experience with various JBOSS releases that must be around 30 secs.

If the above is your case you have two options:

1. Increase globally the tx timeout value, which I don't recommend.
2. Use the custom @TransactionTimeout annotation or tweak the JBOSS jboss-ejb3.xml deployment descriptor.

Examples:

With annotation :

@TransactionTimeout(value = 10, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)

With jboss-ejb3.xml:

```
<assembly-descriptor>
    <container-transaction>
        <method>
            <ejb-name>BeanWithTimeoutValue</ejb-name>
            <method-name>*</method-name>
            <method-intf>Local</method-intf>
        </method>
        <tx:trans-timeout>
            <tx:timeout>10</tx:timeout>
            <tx:unit>Seconds</tx:unit>
        </tx:trans-timeout>
    </container-transaction>
</assembly-descriptor>
```

All the above are from Jboss 7.1 documentation, take particular notice that the above works only for a new transaction.

See:
[Jboss 7.1 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+3+Reference+Guide)

Comment: To simplify my issue I didn't mention any other databases, so let's assume that I have DB1 only. I'm sure that it's not transaction timeout. It is firewall killing a connection.

Comment: Again I'm missing something. You say "a firewall is killing a connection". Which connection logically this must be the WS connection. Right?